# Django session lost due to calling another server via iframe

Tags: python, django, iframe

I have two development servers written with Python/Django - one API server(it's not solely an API server; it has UI and etc.), and another one is a demo app used to serve data by communicating to the API server. I invoke the demo app with iframe in the API server. **After successfully getting response from the demo app, the original user session of the API server is lost(supposed to have two sessions -- one from the user of the API server, one from communication between the demo app and the API server)**.

Any idea what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running both on the same server, the session cookie might be overwritten since they both expect a `sessionid` cookie. If a sessionid doesn't exist a new one is generated, so when you access the outer app, you get a sessionid cookie, and that gets passed to the iframe app which doesn't recognize it and generates a new one. Try giving each app it's own unique [`SESSION_COOKIE_NAME`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name)

Comment: they are two server run on two different port

Comment: We are talking about different servers, I am referring to the computer serving the app, not the django development server. You are running both development servers on the same computer?